# Spark: returning all regex matches for each dataset row

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset loaded from a .csv file (imitated by `ds` here) which contains 2 rows: one with the publishing date of an article (`publishDate`), and one with mentioned names and their character offset in that article (`allNames`).

I'm trying to count the amount of times a name is mentioned per day, and I thought it would be good to start with removing the character offsets in `allNames` by mapping a regex operation. Have a look at the code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

case class Data(publishDate: String, allNames: String)

val ds = Seq(Data("01-01-2018", "Channel One,628;Channel One,755;Channel One,1449;Channel One"),
             Data("01-02-2018", "Waite Park,125;City Food,233;Adobe Flash Player,348;Charter Channel,554")).toDS()

val pattern = """([^\;\,]+),\d+""".r

val processed_ds = ds.map(data => (data.publishDate, (for (m <- pattern.findAllMatchIn(data.allNames)) yield m.group(1)).toList))
```

Which gives a whole list of errors when I call `processed_ds.collect().foreach(println)`.

What is going wrong here?

NOTE: I am new to Scala.

Edit:

The expected output from `processed_ds.collect().foreach(println)` would be:

```
("01-01-2018", List("Channel One", "Channel One", "Channel One", "Channel One"))
("01-02-2018", List("Waite Park", "City Food", "Adobe Flash Player", "Charter Channel"))
```

Or would this be easier achieved with a split operation of some sort?

Comment: Can you please provide expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If regexp is not mandatory, can be solved with "split" function:

```
val result = ds.map(v => (v.publishDate, v.allNames.split(";").map(p => p.split(",")(0)).toList))
result.collect().foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
(01-01-2018,List(Channel One, Channel One, Channel One, Channel One))
(01-02-2018,List(Waite Park, City Food, Adobe Flash Player, Charter Channel))
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.